# Unable to get type of object property contained in table

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is that possible to get the type of object property if that object is contained in table?
Please look at the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAhgIwDYFMA8AlAeQHVEsAPKLMAEwGdE40ArLaAGkQGlSKq7EAohQBOKaDgDWWAJ5xgiQkQ60owmGADmAPi0AKAN4AoRIghwMIALZhabY4mopUdgL4AuREZNmL12h4BBYVFpHC8TRBhqD057EwBhLAwMD10ANxQLLA9FAG1OAF0ASkQAXi1EFDBpexcte0dUQOCUUMV6lxLw4SwoEGEkMBBkwxdDQ1RMLAN7HysbD1y4z2WTKI8AIgAHYTgtgEYNuwiIxOTUjKyS8sRLkCxll2OI8JP1xG3drYAmI9XEM4pRDpTL3a4VO4PE5jEwFZ4OJwoRarV4nHZ7fabOjAagaWjADR-E4RdE-DzfADMABZqd8qQBWVZPcbE1Ekr6Yj5MDQAC2ATCYEiJxMQpO+HmpADYqZLJUy4gVRkUgA).

```
function table<ROW extends object, K extends Extract<keyof ROW, string>>({
  columns,
  data,
}: {
  columns: Array<{
    id: K
    Cell: (value: ROW[K]) => any
  }>
  data: Array<ROW>
}) {
  return null
}

table({
  columns: [
    {
      id: "prop1",
      Cell: (value) => value
    },
    {
      id: "prop2",
      Cell: (value) => value
    }
  ],
   data: [
     {
       prop1: "dsfdgsfg",
       prop2: 23434245
     },

     {
       prop1: "jghfjjk",
       prop2: 346466
     }
   ]
})
```

What I want to have is typed `value` (`string` for `prop1` or `number` for `prop2` instead of `string | number` for both keys) in columns Cell component.

Comment: what is the logic here? why is `value` for `prop2` `number` ? In the `data` array we have `prop2` with both `number` and `string` values...

Comment: Sorry, it was mistake, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the argument in `Cell` the correct type like this:

```
function table<
  R extends any[]
>({
  columns,
  data,
}: {
  columns: { 
    [K in keyof R & `${bigint}`]: {
      [K2 in keyof R[K]]: { 
        id: R[K][K2], Cell: (arg: R[K][K2]) => any }
      }[keyof R[K]]
    }[keyof R & `${bigint}`][],
  data: [...R]
}) {
  return null
}
```

For the `column` property I created a union of all possible prop names with the corresponding `Cell` function type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAhgIwDYFMA8AoRRAJUSwA8oswATAZ0RTAE8BtAXTwD4AKAbwMQQ4GEAFswtADQDqKVNIC%20ALkT9CQkeNoreiAYRYBpRDCQBrLEzjBiiAGSIABgBJeaGAHNTUBY7Y79QkQjACYTc0trYiM2f1U9IMSTahVDEMlEAGEsDAwVbhQAJw8VIhjQtgBKRABeTgZmRAVAwgUWCysbMsNYwLaOqJIHFzdPb182dmlCWVQVQqwUagQMJmCAOk2iDgVqtUQFqBBCpDAQXLxmvFRMLD4BDTEJFRZA-cSYFMQAIgAHQrgvwAjN9pklsrl8gA3FAiLDVOqIGFwvpgwjvIKfFR-AG-EKglpZHJ5RDcZEgeG1erkrB9ARsNGzFAvFoYoL-QFA7F0YDUDy0YAeAlJQgcvEqEIAZgALDKQtKAKwtBRo9GExBirk-ABWHgAFsBtdqzMKRWKQhKZXLFcr9DtKkA)